# what is wrong with exp(1 - 1j).real

Tags: python

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ngum8.png)

I do not how to tackle with the exponent function with complex in power[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ngum8.png)

Comment: What is `exp()`?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Unfortunately this isn't a discussion forum or tutorial service. Please take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.  You should invest some time working your way through [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html), practicing the examples. It will give you an introduction to the tools Python has to offer and you may even start to get ideas for solving your problem.

Comment: [cmath:9.3.2. Power and logarithmic functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/cmath.html#power-and-logarithmic-functions)

Answer (score 2):

Complex aware math functions are in module cmath:

```
>>> import math, cmath
>>> math.exp(1-1j)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can't convert complex to float
>>> cmath.exp(1-1j)
(1.4686939399158851-2.2873552871788423j)
```

Answer (score -1):

Use numpy for this it is much easier

```
np.real(np.exp(1-1j))
```

> 1.4686939399158851